# mysql - calculations

Tags: mysql

I want to return the result of a simple calculation but I am unsure on how to do this. My table is as follows:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(fb.engineer_id) AS `total_feedback`, 
    SUM(fb.rating) AS `total_rating`, fb.engineer_id 
FROM 
    `feedback` AS fb
```

Now when I return the result I use PHP to make the calulation but now I want to order the results (this query is nested in a much bigger one) by the result.

The calculation is as follows:

```
$p = ((($total_rating*20)*$total_feedback)/10);
```

Can this be done in the initial query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
SELECT
    COUNT(fb.engineer_id) AS `total_feedback`, 
    SUM(fb.rating) AS `total_rating`, fb.engineer_id 
FROM 
    `feedback` AS fb 
ORDER BY total_rating*20*total_feedback/10
```

or if you want that column in your result:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(fb.engineer_id) AS `total_feedback`, 
    SUM(fb.rating) AS `total_rating`, fb.engineer_id 
    total_rating*20*total_feedback/10 AS p
FROM 
    `feedback` AS fb 
ORDER BY p
```

Comment: says unknown column total_rating

Comment: Ok, used your first method and did the calculation in first parent query which now works! cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not have `groub by` clause, so it just return one row, then how do you want to order your results?